# Variables taking two different values in an IF statement

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible for `$variable` to take different values at the point of the `INSERT` query? If my statement is false, how can I achieve this.
Thank you.

```
  if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $variable = "Foo" ;
  }

  elseif (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $variable = "Bar" ;
  }

$sql  = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl
             tbl_id, variable
              VALUES('$id', '$variable'");
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually asking. Your current code will work, so I don't see a problem there. The only thing I would recommend is that you could just use `else { ... }` instead of your current `elseif()`.

Comment: I'm trying to insert a value into the database, depending if ID is set. Any of the two values has to be entered into the database, if i change the variable name, do i have to write two insert statements?

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens?

Comment: @zeroOne .... I tried it and it was the initial value of $variable was inserted into db, while the value of ID was not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One variable can hold only one value at once and in your code it's valid. If `id` is available it'll have `Foo`, otherwise it'll have `Bar` and alternatively you can write it in one line as follows:

```
$variable=isset($_GET['id']) ? 'Foo' : 'Bar';
```

Then you can use your `$variable` variable later in your script. It'll contain at least one value `Foo` or `Bar`.

Comment: The latter is what i'm getting into the database. Please where could the problem be?

Comment: `Foo` or `Bar` will be inserted into the database because `$variable` will have at least on value.

Comment: I still don't really get the problem but I'm glad this answer solved @user1378680's problem. :P

Answer (score 0):

No. A variable in ANY language can only ever have a single value in it at any given time. If you want to two different values, you'll need to two different variables.

Comment: I'm trying to insert a value into the database, depending if ID is set. Any of the two values has to be entered into the database, if i change the variable name, do i have to write two insert statements?

Comment: Your query is nonsense. `insert into tbl (tbl_id, foo) values (?, 'foo')` makes no sense. Why dynmaically specify a field name, then set the value of that field to BE the field name?

Answer (score 0):

This is valid because $variable will be assigned to FOO or BAR and then inserted into the database.  The variable, $variable will however only ever contain 1 value depending on your conditional statement.

Comment: I'm trying to insert a value into the database, depending if ID is set. Any of the two values has to be entered into the database, if i change the variable name, do i have to write two insert statements?

Comment: What you have programmed is correct and will accomplish this.  2 INSERT statements are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

More clear statment is:

```
   if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
       $my_variable = "Foo" ;
      }
    else{
      $my_variable = "Bar" ;
      }
```

After this code executed you'll have $my_variable which have value:

`Foo` (if id was sent by GET method) OR

`Bar` (if id wasn't sent by GET method)

So You can use your variable later anywhere.

If you want to cheack the variable value, use

```
echo $my_variable;
```

Comment: Thanks... What if i want to have a dynamically generated content for the $my_variable in the else

Comment: No problem, generate it as you wish. And pls vote if unswer was helpfull.